# How to remove outliers above a specified value in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, outliers

I am new to R programming. I have a set of two data series. I need to remove outliers that are above a certain value, for example absolute value of 25. Once those values are identified, they need to be removed from both sets. How would I proceed in identifying these values and removing them?

Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is stored in a vector `v`, then you can do `new.v <- v[v <= 25]` to store all values that are less than or equal to 25 in a new vector `new.v`. You can generalize this to `new.v <- v[some_condition_to_keep_values]`. Note that this works for vectors; it'd be easier to help if you specified what you stored your data in (i.e. a data frame, a matrix, etc).

Comment: thank you for your reply! but how would I know which values were removed, because I need to also remove those corresponding values in the second set